# Karate Framework - How to setup multiple api request header details in one variable in karate-config.js file

Tags: karate

I'm new to karate framework, To test one "GET" request for a end point URI. I have this request headers details which needs to use to test the "GET" end point `( x-bpi-client-context, x-bpi-service-context, x-bpi-version and Authorization )` , how can we declare all this four values in in one variable in karate-config.js file.

I'm unable to map all this four values in one variable in Karate-config.js file.

I tried the below syntax code in karate.config:

```
karate.configure('headers', {x-bpi-client-context: 'MUGIL' ,x-bpi-service-context : {"client"{"user_tracking_column"}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you have dashes in the key name please surround with quotes:

```
karate.configure('headers', { 'x-bpi-client-context': 'MUGIL' });
```